# How to customize UIBarButtonItem with @IBDesignables?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

```
@IBDesignable class AttributedBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem {

    @IBInspectable var fontSize: CGFloat = 22 {

        didSet {

            let attributes: [String: AnyObject] = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Icomoon", size: fontSize)!]
            setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, forState: .Normal)
        }
    }
}
```

This is how it looks like in **Attributes inspector**

[image]

But it doesnt change anything:

[image]

Comment: I have many @IBDesignable widgets in my project and sometimes Storyboard fails to render them. Try to clean build folder, restart and rebuild to be sure that issue is in code and not in xCode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be customized ONLY via `UINavigationBar`:

```
@IBDesignable class AttributedNavigationBar: UINavigationBar {

    @IBInspectable var transparentBackground: Bool = false {

        didSet {

            setBackgroundImage(transparentBackground ? UIImage() : nil, forBarMetrics: .Default)
            shadowImage = transparentBackground ? UIImage() : nil
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var fontSize: CGFloat = 18
    @IBInspectable var icomoonLeftBarButtonItems: Bool = false {

        didSet {

            let attributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Icomoon", size: fontSize)!]

            if let leftBarButtonItems = topItem?.leftBarButtonItems {

                for leftBarButtonItem in leftBarButtonItems {
                    leftBarButtonItem.setTitleTextAttributes(icomoonLeftBarButtonItems ? attributes : nil, forState: .Normal)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

`@IBDesignable` doesn't work with `UIBarButtonItem`, because `@IBDesignable` only works with `UIView` subclasses (on iOS), and `UIBarButtonItem` is not a `UIView` subclass.

Comment: Wow, I think it is simple and clear answer:) Thx @rob.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@IBInspectable var fontSize: CGFloat {
    set {
        let attributes: [String: AnyObject] = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Icomoon", size: newValue)!]
        setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, forState: .Normal)
    }
    get {
        return self.fontSize
    }
}
```